Interpretation of the TTC and PIT probability of default in the Vasicek model
The well known 2-factor Gaussian model assumes that the default behaviour of a client is ruled by a latent variable defined as:
\begin{align}
y=\sqrt{\rho}Z+\sqrt{1-\rho}\xi
\end{align}
where $Z$ and $\xi$ are independent standard Gaussian r.v. representing the systemic and idiosyncratic risk sources respectively.
The default event is defined as
$$D:=\{y\leq K\}$$
for some $K\in\mathbb R$.
The unconditional probability of default, i.e.
$$\mathbb{P}(D)=\Phi(K)=:p,$$
is sometimes referred to as the "TTC" (Through-the-cycle) PD. This is what somehow confuses me, in the IRB world the term "TTC" is used to refer to models which are unsensitive to macro economical (systemic) fluctuations, and where the only source of variability comes from idiosyncratic factors.
In this case $\mathbb{P}(D)$ is defined by taking into consideration the latent variable which depends on both risk sources.
In IFRS9, we sometimes use the IRB transition matrices to derive the TTC PD, and this is used to compute the PIT (point-in-time) PD using the Vasicek's formula, i.e.
$$PD^{PPI}(Z)=\mathbb{P}(D|Z)=\Phi\left(\frac{\Phi^{-1}(PD^{TTC})-\sqrt{\rho}Z}{\sqrt{1-\rho}}\right),$$
where we are "assuming" that $K=\Phi^{-1}(PD^{TTC})$. This assumption I find problematic, $K$ is defined as $K=\Phi^{-1}(p)$ but I find it hard to say that $p$ (defined above) is a TTC probability of default.
I understand that under the rather simplistic assumptions of the Gaussian model everything works fine, and I don't have issues with the math,  but from a conceptual point of view I struggle connecting the dots.
Could someone clarify if my interpretation is correct, or point out what am I missing?
